# How do I transfer 100 GB of xml files over sockets in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

We have a machine with tcp socket opened listening to files.

I can connect to the socket in my C# console application using System.Net.Sockets

I want to read data in an xml file (100 Gb) and send it across via socket.

What's the best way?  Is there a microsoft.net library that can break it into packets or stream it and send it across?

Do I have to read it chunk by chunk myself?

Please suggest

Comment: Sockets is a streaming protocol already.  What do you mean by "chunk by chunk"?

Comment: i didn't know that.  do i have to load all of the file contents in an array and call Send method of the socket or is there another way to send data to the client?

Comment: if i set socket type as stream and send 100 gb of data, will it automatically stream it for me and break it into packets?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special that you should do, once you open a socket connection, you can keep it open as long as you want. It would be nice to gzip the xml file, transfer it and then use it on the server. I would expect at least 50:1 compression rate for xml files.

Edit:
You have to pay attention when you read the file for sending, to use a buffer to read some lines, send, empty buffer, rinse and repeat and do not load the file on client then start sending data through socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

This task although may seem quite easy/solvable it has a lot of caveats. The best thing you can do here is use some kind of middleware to do it. A good example of middleware is ICE.

http://www.zeroc.com/doc/Ice-3.3.1/manual/Hello.4.5.html

I'm not sure if it's a good candidate for this particular job, but you'll find something yourself..

Answer (score 0):

If you have an HTTP server on the other end (or can put one there) then you might want to look at [Windows Background Intelligent Transfer Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This will hide a lot of complexity around retries, requesting ranges, etc.

There is an article on interacting with the COM API from C# on [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188766.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If the 100Gb is troubling you, you might want to read this for ideas:

[Compressed XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082285/best-compression-algorithm-for-xml)