# Log entire SOAP request or only parameters in it?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sqlite, logging

I have synchronization application that sends requests to web service every 10 seconds and makes some data chengings in local database and vice-versa. For my convenience and for solving of some disputes I want to log any pair of request and response SOAP messages.

But as my experience tell me, it will take a lot of space, stuffing SQLite database with a same requests and responses.

How can I achieve same level of log detalisation with fewer disk space?
In fact, is there a benefit of logging whole messages? Maybe we can just cut parameter values and log it instead of full messages?

Maybe there is another mechanism that can compress messages (or extend/get a full message with some part of data?) and store a fewer data, but with ability to get source message where it needed?

Samples:
Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetModifiedItems>
         <tem:Key>abcdef</tem:Key>
      </tem:GetModifiedItems>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetModifiedItemsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetModifiedItemsResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Exchange" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:Body i:type="a:lst">
               <a:List>
                  <a:BaseItem i:type="a:asd">
                     <a:ISDELETED i:nil="true"/>
                     <a:ID>1</a:ID>                     
                     <a:SYSUSER>b2</a:SYSUSER>
                  </a:BaseItem>
                  <a:BaseItem i:type="a:asd">
                     <a:ISDELETED i:nil="true"/>
                     <a:ID>2</a:ID>
                     <a:SYSUSER>b3</a:SYSUSER>
                  </a:BaseItem>
               </a:List>
            </a:Body>
            <a:Msg>SUCCESS</a:Msg>
         </GetModifiedItemsResult>
      </GetModifiedItemsResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, the solution depends on whether you want to store the whole message or just tracing the calls and a few other data.

If you do not have to store the whole message, I would definitely suggest you to install [Microsoft AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx). AppFabric is a set of integrated technologies that makes it easier to perform a lot of things including monitoring WCF services hosted on IIS, and it’s free!. AppFabric setup is pretty straightforward and will add new functionalities/icons to your IIS.

We’re using AppFabric + SQL Server Express on production environment to trace some WCF calls. Turning on tracing is pretty simple; you can set the tracing level, target DB, how much history you want to keep, size limits and so on… Moreover there’s a pretty cool user interface that lets you query all the traces stored (it shows you how much calls have been traced, how much fails, ...). The nice thing is that you may have the error description in case of faulted calls. It’s also possible to add UserDefined data in AppFabric traces. More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677276%28v=azure.10%29.aspx).

Now, if you need to store the whole message, as @Aron said, I would chose to go with NoSQL and more particularly with [logstash](http://logstash.net/). 
As written on their site:

> logstash is a tool for managing events and logs. You can use it to
>   collect logs, parse them, and store them for later use (like, for
>   searching). Speaking of searching, logstash comes with a web interface
>   for searching and drilling into all of your logs.

logstash is based on elasticsearch.

The last thing you have to find out is defining the right time/place to store the message, probably with the use of custom WCF behavior.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to compress XML is to store multiple documents at once and apply any general purpose compression algorithm of your choice to it. The key is to compress multiple messages at once so that the compressor can exploit the extreme redundancies present in repeated XML structure.

This works so well that dedicated XML compression often is unnecessary. Common algorithms like "gzip/deflate" or more powerful ones like LZMA (7zip) are very, very good at exploiting this. All they do is combine repeated substrings (like they are present in XML).

So you could buffer all XML messages for 10 seconds and save them in one binary blob somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. It is pretty simple to setup WCF to log everything. An example is shown [here](http://cgeers.com/2011/05/10/wcf-message-logging/). You want to use the IMessageInspector interface.

As for the second part of the question. Using large amount of data storage. I have two answers for you. You WILL use up a large amount of data storage because

1. Each message is large (XML is not know for efficiency of data storage).
2. You are storing lots of messages.

Hence you want to reduce the contribution from each part.

The first is as you rightly surmised. You could reduce the payload size by compressing the data. From simple information theory we know that how compressable the data is depends on the nature of the data. In this case XML, which can easily be compressed. [Depending on how much of the schema is known before hand you can compress it more or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082285/best-compression-algorithm-for-xml).

Secondly you can reduce the number of payloads. By simply truncating the number of stored requests regularly you can limit the storage.

However I would finally want to point out that I would most definitely NOT use SQLite as the storage mechanism. From my experience the P/Invoke overhead will severely limit performance of your server. Also SQLite has a very poor concurrency model, limiting the number of concurrent request on your server as well.

To be frank, I have to ask if you need anything over using just flat files for storage, or perhaps I might suggest to switch to a XML NoSQL solution, if you need querying.

An added bonus to using a XML NoSQL database is that you can put it off box and query it even when the application server goes down.

Now, as for whether you should extract the data out of the XML instead or store it in an incompatible format...I would argue that it would be counter productive. By storing the actual request you can write a small app to resend the request to regression test.

Comment: NoSQL looks good. But could I use it as non client-server tool? I chose SQLite because it is pretty easy to deploy, even doesn't require any server, just flat file with quering feature. So, quering feature is pretty benefitly for me.

Comment: I would recommend against NoSQL if you want a pure client solution. I would still advise AGAINST SQLite. I would prefer using SQL CE if you can (you don't need to access the database from, say JAVA). Another option would be to use the Windows EventLog. It would handle all of your event lifetime issues.

Comment: OK, thanks. But what the difference between SQL CE and SQLite? They are just the same technologies AFAIK?

Comment: Hugely different. But the important point is that SQL CE was built from the ground up to work with .net whilst SQLite has a very inefficient P/Invoke wrapper to a C++ library. The result is that SQL CE works faster and better on .net applications.

Comment: Looks good, thanks! Could you please say some words on logs rotating? Will it decrease complexity and fillness of current work file and get it faster and smaller for using? Please update your answer about that. Another one thing I wondering is log rotation strategies and techniques for SQL CE logging.

Comment: Yeah...so that is kind of the primary reason I prefer to do my logging outside of SQL. Log rotation. `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` will do Log Rotation automatically. `log4Net` will do log rotation if you tell it to. But SQL is inherently designed against this sort of thing...

Answer (score 1):

Logs perform 2 major purposes:

1. Debugging/Tracing application problems when they arise
2. Audit trail

To achieve these, you need to log as much as is available. So Log the entire SOAP message.
To save disk space, you can store in adequately named (including date and time) flat files that are compressed intermittently and archived periodically.

Good luck. Hope this helps