# optimize Large XML File in c#

Tags: c#

How to handle large XML file in size. I know the following are affecting the size of XML file.
    1) Repeated Pattern Occurance, eg. dfd dfser,...
    2) Pattern height and size (in bytes)
    3) Indentation 
    4) Multiple spaces
    5) Flattening patterns

My question is how to achieve above parameters in c#. i googled about this, but couldn't get any examples.

Can any body help me to achieve this.

Update 1: 
In a compression algorithm the size of xml file is reduced, but i would like to reduce the file size by programming.I make a xml file from a class,
Eg:

```
<assets>
<asset>
<id> 1</id>
<Hardware></Hardware> ....

</asset>

<asset>
<id> 1</id>
<Hardware> mouse</Hardware>
<Hardware>keyboard</Hardware> ....

</asset>
</assets>
```

Like this i have to make for more than 1000 asset with more config information with above xml, here the same xml tag is repeated again and again. how to make a optimized xml file from the c# class.

Comment: What's the link between your xml structure and C# ? In which way C# could help you to have lighter XML files ? Your question is not clear at all for me.

Comment: What you mean by "optimize"? State your requirements in question, then SO might be able to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best compression algorithm for XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082285/best-compression-algorithm-for-xml)

Comment: If size is an issue, consider using attributes for some elements where possible. The ID for example- it's a minor optimization, but id="1" takes up less space than <id>1</id>, at least when serialized.

Comment: i know this is not answering the question... but if the xml markup is simple... just convert to json and then transfer, then convert back to xml if needed. I assume you are using build-in xml serializer to generate your xml. also quote "My question is how to achieve above parameters in c#" does not really make for a valid question.

Comment: Use a tool to convert your c# class into XML or Json. Understand the limitations/advantages of XML and the tools which you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use GZip compression like this? Even at fastest mode it will almost completely eliminate file size overhead produced by repeating XML tags.

```
[Serializable]
public class Asset
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Hardware { get; set; }
}

...

List<Asset> assets = new List<Asset> {new Asset {Id = 1, 
                Hardware = new List<string> {"mouse", "keyboard"}}};

//serialize
using (GZipStream zs = new GZipStream(File.Create("compressed_xml.zip"),
                                            CompressionLevel.Fastest))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (List<Asset>));
    serializer.Serialize(zs, assets);
}

//deserialize
using (GZipStream zs = new GZipStream(File.Open("compressed_xml.zip",FileMode.Open), 
                             CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Asset>));
    assets=(List<Asset>) serializer.Deserialize(zs);
}
```